# Criando pastas dentro de Arquivos de programas

Tags: c#

Estou tendo problemas para criar pastas dentro de arquivos de programas.

Onde trabalho existe uma aplicação que só funciona se os arquivos estiverem dentro de arquivos de programas e o processo de criação das pastas hoje é totalmente manual.

Ninguém se prontificou em fazer um instalador que automatizasse isso, então, como sou graduando em informática, resolvi pegar esta tarefa até mesmo como desafio.

O problema que estou encontrando é o permissionamento do Windows para criação das pastas dentro de arquivos de programas, pois, se fosse em outro lugar iria de boa.

Eu preciso antes de criar as pastas ter acesso como administrador para criar as pastas no computador.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
// Verifica qual radio button está selecionado.
if (rd_golden.Checked)
{
    //Cria o diretorio para o Golden e faz o procedimentos locais
    string Golden = @"C:\Program Files\Comercial\Golden";
    if (!Directory.Exists(Golden))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Golden);
        MessageBox.Show("Diretório Criado com Sucesso!!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Diretório já Existe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque o programa só funciona se os arquivos estiverem dentro de arquivos de programas?

Comment: Se você estiver executando o programa com privilégios de Administrador você consegue criar a pasta! Acho que não existe uma forma de fazer isso automaticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode simplesmente ignorar as permissões que são aplicadas às pastas. Até porque, se pudesse, as permissões seriam inúteis, não acha?

Uma alternativa é rodar o seu instalador com privilégios administrativos para poder escrever nas pastas que deseja.

É possível forçar que a aplicação seja executada apenas com privilégios administrativos adicionando um novo arquivo *manifest* e adicionando a seguinte tag a ele

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

---

Aliás, fica uma dica: evite usar o caminho *hardcodado* isso pode trazer problemas futuramente. É possível usar `Environment.SpecialFolders` para retornar o caminho desta pasta.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder,Fiz a alteração do "requireAdministrator" e apareceu a mensagem: Gravidade Código Descrição Projeto Arquivo Linha Estado de supressão
Erro  ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'. CriandoPastaePermissionar

Comment: Ah sim. @FabioAragão Isso é mostrado justamente pelo motivo descrito, se você for usar ClickOnce, precisará fazer algo pra "dar a volta" nisto.